# errors Alerts and using str_replace “ within double quoted string

Tags: php, str-replace

Hello I have to do a `str_replace` but have issued with double quotes within the string. All in all when the error appears on my site it appears as:

> Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.

But the site is multilingual thus I have to change this. So I have the following:

```
$errorsAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.', "{$record['cpw']}", $errorsAlerts);
```

The above does not work. I have tried using an escape key for the double quoted string:

```
$errorsAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of \"most common passwords\", please choose a more secure password.', "{$record['cpw']}", $errorsAlerts);
```

But that does not work either. Can anyone advise me how to fix this?

Comment: And "does not work" mean what _exactly_? No replacement? Wrong replacement? Crash?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: The first one should work if that exact text appears in `$errorsAndAlerts`.  Most likely you have encoded quotes `&quot;`.

Comment: `echo $errorsAndAlerts;` and then do a view source on the page.

Comment: thank you,

IT should be $errorsAlerts on each statement. 
I do not get an error, it is just it does not translate for me.

On my other errors without the "" in them they replace nicely. it is only this one specific error that the  str_replace does not work. and I believe it is down to the  "most common passwords" double quotes that are in use. but as I have mentioned escaping them as I have shown does not work.

Comment: the error I get showing on my webpage is 

Password found in list of "most common passwords", please choose a more secure password.

thus I wanted the str_replace to show something else. but it does not work. I do use the str_replace on other errors on the same page and show show nicely.

Comment: Can you execute following debug and dump, and update your question with the output? `ob_start();
var_dump($errorsAlerts);
$dump = ob_get_clean();
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($dump) . '</pre>';`

Comment: @AbraCadaver  wow I didnt fully understand what you ment but the penny has just dropped and I have done the following and it has worked wonderfully. thank you very much

    $errorsAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of &quot;most common passwords&quot;, please choose a more secure password.', "{$record['cpw']}", $errorsAlerts);

Comment: Inside [single-quote strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), the backslash is used to escape a single quote (`\'`) or a backslash (`\\ `). [*"All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash."*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). This means `\"` in a single-quote string represents two characters: a backslash (`\ `) followed by a double quote (`"`).

Comment: Mark answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have encoded quotes as HTML entities `&quot;`.  You can view the source of the page to confirm.  This would be the replacement:

```
$errorsAlerts = str_replace('Password found in list of &quot;most common passwords&quot;, please choose a more secure password.', $record['cpw'], $errorsAlerts);
```

Also notice that you only need `$record['cpw']` and not `"{$record['cpw']}"`.